# Search doesn't work anymore for older questions, neither does the "Related" bar

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, search, related-questions

**UPDATE** March 11: The situation is becoming unbearable. Internally there's no way to find older questions, and I expect that this will invite lots of duplicate questions on the main sites.

If I [ask a new question on TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with the title "**How to repeat top rows (column headings) on every page**" then the system does *not* offer the [question with the very same title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11380/how-to-repeat-top-rows-column-headings-on-every-page) in the "Questions that may already have your answer". I also can't find the question with searching for [**repeat top rows**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=repeat+top+rows). A very similar question was asked today: [How to continue table on multiple pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101898). My only chance to find the possible duplicate was via a google search [site:tex.stackexchange.com/questions long table with same heading on every page](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:tex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+long+table+with+same+heading+on+every+page), the "Related" bar didn't help at all.

Please, *please* fix this soon!

**UPDATE** March 12: Hmm, it appears that the problem was fixed yesterday, which was *very* soon. A short official explanation would be nice so that my bounty isn't just lost `:-)`

<sup>Original post below the line</sup>

---

This question was just asked on TeX.se: [**Command with variable number of arguments**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101312). I was *sure* that there was a very similar question before, so I tried to find it in the "Related" bar, but to no avail. Then I tried the search, e.g. with ["number of arguments"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22number+of+arguments%22). Still nothing. Finally I managed to find it in the "Related" bar of [another related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument/314#314): The question I had been looking for (for at least 5 very intense minutes!) was [**A macro with variable number of arguments**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10404)!!

How can this be? The question titles are almost the same, so why isn't the old question in the "Related" bar of the new one? And why don't I find it with the site's search functionality? Is this a bug?

Update March 7: That question I was looking for has another title now, and it has recent activity (which seems to be relevant), so let me give another example: Searching for [**encoding family** is:question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=encoding+family+is%3Aquestion) does *not* lead to my question [How do I identify the **encoding** and **family** of a new math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9296) Why not?

Comment: See also this question on meta.tex.se: [Is full text search not working any more?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3355/2693).

Comment: In addition to Alan: In comments below the linked question you can see some other IMHO impressive examples.

Comment: BTW Why not the tag “bug”?

Comment: @Speravir: OK, I'll add the tag and hope that more visibility of the question helps. By the way, another bug: your two comments didn't appear in my inbox!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with several indexes having an incorrect version of the stem parser from the original elastic move when we migrated operations to NYC.  This was corrected yesterday when I noticed it combing through our shards.

Apologies this took so long to fix, we've been focusing on some other areas but I'll be giving search a bit of love this week.

Comment: There is another issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22coffee+stains%22+is%3Aquestion does find only one question, leaving out the quotation marks finds both existing: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=coffee+stains+is%3Aquestion Since in the "Advanced Search Tips" the encapsulation into quotes is explicitly mentioned for finding phrases I would call it clearly a bug.

Comment: "A bit of love" for the search sounds great: +1, ✓ and +50 from me. Thanks for the fix, it's already a lot better now.

Comment: @Speravir - this is a known issue with the words having extra content around them and not split on spaces...we're looking for a good middle ground there.